# Rounded Rect for Context Menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a horizontal stackpanel that has a custom button, that when clicked, opens a context menu to the right of the button.  I'd like that context menu to have a rounded rect.  Is tehre a way to do that?  I thought I could wrap the  in a  element, but ContextMenu doesn't respond to Border.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to Style the ContextMenu element like so:

```
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Usage:*

```
ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();

m.Items.Add("Item 1");
m.Items.Add("Item 2");
m.Items.Add("Item 3");

m.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
m.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Right;
m.IsOpen = true;
```